# Difference between reference and regular variable in C++?

Tags: c++, reference

After you define a reference in C++, is there any difference between the reference and a normal variable?

For example, after I define a reference in the following code:
int x = 10;
int& xRef = x;

Is there any way to tell that xRef is a reference to an int, rather than just being a normal int? Is int& its own type?

Comment: There's definitely a difference when it's a member variable of a class, because they'll behave differently in copy constructors. I'm not sure if variables with other scopes have similar subtle distinctions of that sort.

Comment: References, like pointers, can be left dangling. References also require initialization.

Comment: A reference is an identifier which acts as an *alias* to variable.  A reference does not construct an object.  The end of the scope of the reference does not destruct an object (well... if it is a const reference to a temporary it will extend the life of the temporary object and destruct it at the end of the reference's scope).  A reference *might* be implemented as a pointer, but maybe not be either — implementation detail.  A reference cannot bind to a dereferenced null pointer.  Polymorphism necessitates using pointers and/or references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to tell that xRef is a reference to an int, rather than just being a normal int?

You can use [std::is_reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_reference):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main ()
{
    int i = 0;
    int& ri = i;
    
    if (std::is_reference <decltype (i)>::value)
        std::cout << "i is a reference\n";

    if (std::is_reference <decltype (ri)>::value)
        std::cout << "ri is a reference\n";
}
```

Output: `ri is a reference`

So,

> Is int& its own type?

Yes it is.